# Scala proper use of break to return

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
private def hasRole(role: String): Boolean = {
  var hasRole = false;
  if(getUserDetails.isDefined){

    // getAuthorities returns java.util.Collection<GrantedAuthority>
    val authorities: util.Collection[_ <:GrantedAuthority] = getUserDetails.get.getAuthorities
    // Wrap the collection is a Scala class 
    val authoritiesWrapper = JCollectionWrapper.apply(authorities);
    for(authority <- authoritiesWrapper.iterator){
      if(authority.getAuthority == role){
        hasRole = true;
        scala.util.control.Breaks.break  
      }
    }
  }
  hasRole
}
```

The question is, is `scala.util.control.Breaks.break` the correct way to`return` when I've found the role? Doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Well, first of all, you haven't set the scope of the break. You need to have a `breakable { }` clause surrounding the code that you will break from.

Comment: Also what does _ <:GrantedAuthority mean? I got this from IntelliJ's code complete. <-- post as separate question. I'm removing from this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use breakable, you need to do it like so:

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
breakable {
  for (i <- 0 to 10000) { if (i>3) break }
}
```

But if you find yourself doing that often, you're probably not using the collections library to its full extent.  Try instead

```
authoritiesWrapper.iterator.exists(_.getAuthority == role)
```

Also, in the example you gave, you could also

```
if (authority.getAuthority == role) return true
```

When to choose which?  In general, you should use the control-flow options in the collections library if you can.  They generally are the fastest and clearest.  Wait, fastest--why is that?  Both `break` and `return` (from within a `for` or other context that requires a closure--basically anything but `if` and `while` and `match`) actually throw a stackless exception which is caught; in the `break` case it's caught by `breakable` and in the `return` case it's caught by the method.  Creating a stack trace is really slow, but even stackless exceptions are kind of slow.

So using the correct collections method--`exists` in this case--is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1. I've put my refactored code in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, is scala.util.control.Breaks.break the correct way
>   toreturn when I've found the role? Doesn't look right to me.

Since your just looking for the first instance of `authority.getAuthority == role` you can use `find` which does exactly that and is the idiomatic way to do this.

```
authoritiesWrapper.iterator.find(authority => authority.getAuthority == role)
```

or more concisely

```
authoritiesWrapper.iterator.find(_.getAuthority == role)
```

These return an `Option` type which you can get the value of `authority` from if it exists.

Comment: This returns Option[_ <:GrantedAuthority]. Do I then need to end my method with `option.isDefined`?

Comment: Yes, I think `isDefined` would provide the same logic you have with `for` and `scala.util.control.Breaks.break`

Answer (score 1):

I can only offer you generalities, but I hope it's at least a little helpful...

Unfortunately, your sample code contains free identifiers, so it's not possible for me to understand what it does without guessing and assuming.

You're thinking about the problem wrong. What is it you're doing here? You're `find`ing a element of a collection. Use the library! It has all manner of such things off-the-shelf.

When it comes to dealing with `Option[Something]` the preferred approach is to `map` over it. If it's a `None`, you get a `None` out. If it's `Some(thing)` then the function you pass to `map` will be applied to `thing` and the result will be `Some(what-your-function-returned-for-thing)`.

Alternatively, and what newcomers to Scala often find more palatable, you can use pattern matching on an `Option` to effectively distinguish the `None` case from the `Some(thing)` case.

When it comes to dealing with Java libraries, it's best to push the conversions from and to the Java collections to the very periphery of your code and keep the bulk of your code idiomatic Scala using native Scala collections.

The same goes for `null`s coming from Java. Turn them into `Option` at the earliest possible time. As a convenience, the `Option(thing)` factory will turn a `thing` that is `null` into a `None` and wrap a non-`null` `thing` in a `Some`

**Addendum**

The upshot is that you really should not be using these control flow mechanisms in this code. They're all based on exceptions (other than `return`) and are rather at odds with Scala's emphasis on using functional programming. The library supports a clean, succinct, efficient implementation of the essetial logic you're trying for. Don't go against the grain like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `return true` and `return false` replacing `hasRole`?

Comment: Most saliently because `return` returns from methods only. If you use it in a function literal (typically an argument to a HOF in the standard library) you don't return from that function, you return from the method in which the HOF is called!

Comment: @Randall Schulz I still wonder how I should break a parallel collection traverse. Break does not work.

Comment: @idonnie: I don't think it's even meaningful to put a break in the "work" function passed to a parallel collection HOF. If what you want to do is "race" several alternative and concurrent code paths to a single solution among many, Futures would work better for you. I seem to recall a pattern that creates that sort of a race-to-the-answer parallelism using Futures, but I can't recall what it was specifically or where I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone, based on @Rex Kerr answer I now have this:

```
private def hasRole(role: String): Boolean = {
  var hasRole: Boolean = false;
  if(getUserDetails.isDefined){
    val authorities: util.Collection[_ <:GrantedAuthority] = getUserDetails.get.getAuthorities
    val authoritiesWrapper = JCollectionWrapper.apply(authorities);
    hasRole = authoritiesWrapper.iterator.exists(_.getAuthority == role)
  }
  hasRole
}
```

which seems to look and feel right. I'm using `exists` to see of the role exists in the collection and then returning that result. By default `false` is returned if the user is not defined (not logged in).

Please comment if this is still not perfect.

Comment: The `hasRole` var serves no purpose.  You could simply delete it and have `if (getUserDetails..) {...} else false` (and instead of setting `hasRole` in the if-statement.  And you create longwinded val names for no apparent reason (as documentation?). Also, since `getUserDetails` is an option, you'd normally let it do the logic (with its `exist` method) instead of adding the if/else: `hasRole(role: String) = getUserDetails.exists{ ud => val auth: util.Collection[_ <: GrantedAuthority] = ud.getAuthorities; JCollectionWrapper(auth).iterator.exists(_.getAuthority == role) }`